# convert deprecated opengl function to modern opengl (3.3)

Tags: opengl, deprecated

i need help to convert the render function of IQM model (void renderiqm()) to modern OpenGL (without the deprecated functions like enableClientState(), etc).

The code of renderiqm() function is here:

https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/demo/gpu-demo.cpp

and these are the shaders:

Vertex Shaders:

```
"#version 120\n"
"#ifdef GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object\n"
"  #extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object : enable\n"
"  layout(std140) uniform animdata\n"
"  {\n"
"     uniform mat3x4 bonemats[80];\n"
"  };\n"
"#else\n"
"  uniform mat3x4 bonemats[80];\n"
"#endif\n"
"attribute vec4 vweights;\n"
"attribute vec4 vbones;\n"
"attribute vec4 vtangent;\n"
"void main(void)\n"
"{\n"
"   mat3x4 m = bonemats[int(vbones.x)] * vweights.x;\n"
"   m += bonemats[int(vbones.y)] * vweights.y;\n"
"   m += bonemats[int(vbones.z)] * vweights.z;\n"
"   m += bonemats[int(vbones.w)] * vweights.w;\n"
"   vec4 mpos = vec4(gl_Vertex * m, gl_Vertex.w);\n"
"   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * mpos;\n"
"   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;\n"
"   mat3 madjtrans = mat3(cross(m[1].xyz, m[2].xyz), cross(m[2].xyz, m[0].xyz), cross(m[0].xyz, m[1].xyz));\n"
"   vec3 mnormal = gl_Normal * madjtrans;\n"
"   vec3 mtangent = vtangent.xyz * madjtrans; // tangent not used, just here as an example\n"
"   vec3 mbitangent = cross(mnormal, mtangent) * vtangent.w; // bitangent not used, just here as an example\n"
"   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color * (clamp(dot(normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * mnormal), gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz), 0.0, 1.0) * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse + gl_LightSource[0].ambient);\n"
"}\n",
```

Fragment Shader:

```
"uniform sampler2D tex;\n"
"void main(void)\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_FragColor = gl_Color * texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);\n"
"}\n",
```

i tried to convert this to modern opengl (vbo, vao, shader version 330, etc), but i dont know which is the fail. Can you show me the correct form to convert it to modern opengl?

PD: im using opengl version 3.3.

**Add Important information:**

Ok, here is my  renderiqm() modified function  :

```
void renderiqm(GLSLProgram& mainShader)
{
    m_matrix->loadIdentity();
    matrixTransformations();

    mainShader.sendUniform("modelYAxisDiff",getYAxisDiff());
    mainShader.sendUniform4x4("modelMatrix", m_matrix->getModelMatrix());
    //envía la matriz de normales
//  mainShader.sendUniform4x4("normalMatrix", m_matrix->getNormalMatrix());
    mainShader.sendUniform3x3("normalMatrix", glm::value_ptr(m_matrix->getNormalMatrix()));
    //envía la matriz de transformación  (modelview)
    mainShader.sendUniform4x4("modelViewMatrix", glm::value_ptr(m_matrix->getModelViewMatrix()));
    mainShader.sendUniform("objColor", m_color);

    m_matrix->pushMatrix(MODEL_MATRIX);

    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubosize, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bonematsoffset, numjoints*sizeof(Matrix3x4), outframe[0].a.v);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, ubo);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    vertex *vert = NULL;

    GLsizei stride = sizeof(vert->position)+sizeof(vert->normal)+sizeof(vert->tangent)+sizeof(vert->texcoord);
    if(numframes > 0)
    {
        stride+= sizeof(vert->blendindex)+sizeof(vert->blendweight);
    }

    //vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);

     //normales
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)sizeof(vert->position));

    //tangente
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)sizeof(vert->position)+sizeof(vert->normal));

    //texturas
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)sizeof(vert->position)+sizeof(vert->normal)+sizeof(vert->tangent));


    if(numframes > 0)
    {
        //blendweight
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, stride, (void*)sizeof(vert->position)+sizeof(vert->normal)+sizeof(vert->tangent)+sizeof(vert->texcoord));

        //blendindex
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
        glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)sizeof(vert->position)+sizeof(vert->normal)+sizeof(vert->tangent)+sizeof(vert->texcoord)+sizeof(vert->blendindex));
    }

    iqmtriangle *tris = NULL;

    //DEBUG
    int i=0;
    for(i = 0; i < m_textureIndices.size(); i++)
    {

        iqmmesh &m = meshes[i];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i] ? textures[i] : notexture);
        tTextures[i].bindTexture(0);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3*m.num_triangles, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &tris[m.first_triangle]);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    if(numframes > 0)
    {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //glPopMatrix();
    m_matrix->popMatrix(MODEL_MATRIX);
}
```

**Clarification:**
mainShader is a tested shader interface that works fine (no errors here),
m_matrix is a GLM interfaces and also works fine.

the vertexShader would be this one:

```
string vAnimationShader = "\n\
#version 330                                                                \n\
                                                                            \n\
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;                                              \n\
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;                                               \n\
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;                                                  \n\
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;                                                   \n\
uniform vec3 objColor;                                                      \n\
\n\
uniform mat4 DepthBiasMVP;                          \n\
smooth out vec4 ShadowCoord;\n\
\n\
smooth out vec2 texCoord;                                                   \n\
smooth out vec3 vNormal;                                                    \n\
smooth out vec3 vEyeSpacePos;                                               \n\
smooth out vec3 vWorldPos;                                                  \n\
smooth out vec3 vObjColor;                                                  \n\
\n\
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;                                   \n\
layout (location = 3) in vec2 inCoord;                                      \n\
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inNormal;                                     \n\
                                                                            \n\
uniform mat3x4 bonemats[80];\n\
\n\
layout (location = 4) in vec4 vweights;\n\
layout (location = 5) in vec4 vbones;\n\
layout (location = 2) in vec4 vtangent;\n\
void main(void)\n\
{\n\
    vObjColor = objColor;                                               \n\
   mat3x4 m = bonemats[int(vbones.x)] * vweights.x;\n\
   m += bonemats[int(vbones.y)] * vweights.y;\n\
  m += bonemats[int(vbones.z)] * vweights.z;\n\
   m += bonemats[int(vbones.w)] * vweights.w;\n\
    vec4 vEyeSpacePosVertex = modelViewMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 1.0);        \n\
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix*vEyeSpacePosVertex;                      \n\
   mat3 madjtrans = mat3(cross(m[1].xyz, m[2].xyz), cross(m[2].xyz, m[0].xyz), cross(m[0].xyz, m[1].xyz));\n\
   vec3 mnormal = inNormal * madjtrans;\n\
   vec3 mtangent = vtangent.xyz * madjtrans; // tangent not used, just here as an example\n\
   vec3 mbitangent = cross(mnormal, mtangent) * vtangent.w; // bitangent not used, just here as an example\n\
   texCoord = inCoord;      \n\
    vec4 vRes = normalMatrix*vec4(inNormal, 0.0);                           \n\
    vNormal = vRes.xyz;                                                     \n\
    vEyeSpacePos = vEyeSpacePosVertex.xyz;                                  \n\
    vec4 vWorldPosVertex = modelMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 1.0);               \n\
    vWorldPos = vWorldPosVertex.xyz;                                        \n\
    ShadowCoord = DepthBiasMVP * vWorldPosVertex;   \n\
}\n\
";
```

i didn't find the error... in the screen i dont see the iqm model.. all the other things draw perfectly, but iqm model doesn't appear.

**IMPORTANT DISCOVERING:**

recently, i have discovered that the problem occurs when the Opengl Context is 3.2+ . if I switch to the 3.1 Version of the opengl context , it works perfectly with my modified function.

i didn't find what the problem is... i associate that with a deprecated function but i cant findit. Please, can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `gl_Color` and `gl_TexCoord` are part of the compatibility profile.  I assume "modern" means "core profile", therefore you can't use these.

Comment: This is a **very** broadly scoped question, though still an interesting challenge to tackle. Look through the OpenGL man pages, google things that don't quite make sense, and try to start converting it. When you run into an issue, narrow it down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that specific question on StackOverflow. You'll get far better results then than you will now.

Comment: Dietrich Epp :  i didn't use gl_Color and gl_TexCoord in the fragment shader (the fragment that you are seeing is an old iqm shader), thanks.

Robert Rouhani: i believe that the question is simplest than it can be. Only need replace the old OpenGL functions for de new functions. Thanks

Comment: recently, i have discovered that the problem occurs when the Opengl Context is 3.2+ . if I switch to the 3.1 Version of the opengl context , it works perfectly with my modified function. 

i didn't find what the problem is... i associate that with a deprecated function but i cant findit. Please, can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the initialization of vbo without a vao, i fixed it and now the model is rendering correctly.